# Are there any automated white box testing tools for T-SQL stored procedures and/or functions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, unit-testing, t-sql

I was wondering if there are any tools similar to [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) that analyze T-SQL stored procedures and functions (instead of managed code) in order to generate meaningful and interesting input values for parameterized unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, no. I've never come across one and another look around has failed to throw one up (I did come across [this article](http://www.scribd.com/doc/18925640/Automated-Database-Testing) on the subject).

The only semi-relevent tools I can suggest are:
[TSQLUnit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/tsqlunit/) -  testing framework for TSQL
[Red Gate's Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm) - for automated test data generation

Or, just writing tests in NUnit. You could create a basic data access layer in (e.g.) .NET, each method wrapping a call to a different sproc with the same parameters to pass through. You could then use a tool like Pex on that data access layer - a sort of proxy approach.

Comment: The article looked promissing at first, but in the end it did not really answer my question. It looks like "AFAIK, **no**" is the answer. +1 for that. I'm going to leave the question open for a couple more days to see if anybody else tips in.

Comment: OK no worries. I'd be surprised if there was such a tool for SQL Server - unit testing at the database level doesn't get as much exposure/attention as testing at the layer up (e.g. .NET). Though I would be interested to hear any other suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the tools mentioned by @AdaTheDev, have you looked at [DbUnit.NET](http://dbunit-net.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: From what I read over there it does not do what I need. Thanks anyway.